# Parent xml in sql query, xpath

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath

I got such xml:

```
< person code="SNIPER">

    <type code="SINGLE" />

<version code="1" dateFrom="2015-03-20" />
</version>

<version code="2" dateFrom="2012-06-15" />
</version>

 < /person>
```

I have sql query:

```
select extract(VALUE(cd_xml), 'version/@code').getstringval() code
       ,cast(to_timestamp_tz(replace(extract(VALUE(cd_xml), 'version/@dateFrom')
                                                   .getstringval(), 'T', ''),
                                           'yyyy-mm-dd') as date) datefrom

from table(xmlsequence(extract(get_xml, '/*/person/version'))) cd_xml
```

It returns me two rows:

```
1  2015-03-10

2  2012-06-15
```

I would like to obtain as a result such rows:

```
single 1  2015-03-10

single 2  2012-06-15
```

or

```
sniper 1  2015-03-10

sniper 2  2012-06-15
```

How to do that??
I tried different thigs with parent clause but i havent made it :(

Comment: How do you decide whether you want 'single' or 'sniper'? Also your XML has `version` nodes that are both self-closing and with explicit close tags, which makes it invalid; and your XPath expects a node *above* `person`. Can you edit the question to make it consistent?

Comment: I simplified problem. I got xml where are few such xmls. The thing is I need rows with "single". But in case I somehow receive rows with sniper i can make another query to connect "sniper" with "single"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `extract` function is deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions060.htm#SQLRF00640); you *can* use it for this but it's better to use [XMLQuery/XMLTable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB1700), e.g. assuming `get_xml` is a function that returns your properly-formatted XML as an XMLType:

```
select *
from xmltable('/persons/person/version'
  passing get_xml
  columns person_code varchar2(10) path './../@code',
    type_code varchar2(10) path './../type/@code',
    version_code number path '@code',
    version_datefrom date path '@dateFrom'
);
```

Demo with static XML, modified from what you posted to match the pattern you used:

```
select *
from xmltable('/persons/person/version'
  passing xmltype('<persons>
  <person code="SNIPER">
    <type code="SINGLE" />
    <version code="1" dateFrom="2015-03-20" />
    <version code="2" dateFrom="2012-06-15" />
  </person>
</persons>')
  columns person_code varchar2(10) path './../@code',
    type_code varchar2(10) path './../type/@code',
    version_code number path '@code',
    version_datefrom date path '@dateFrom'
);

PERSON_COD TYPE_CODE  VERSION_CODE VERSION_DA
---------- ---------- ------------ ----------
SNIPER     SINGLE                1 2015-03-20
SNIPER     SINGLE                2 2012-06-15
```

Your manipulation suggests `dateFrom` is really a full timestamp, more like `'2015-03-20T12:34:56+04:00'`; if you just want the date part of that you can get that more simply too, extracting the column as `timestamp with time zone` and then casting at the end:

```
select person_code, type_code, version_code,
  cast(version_datefrom as date) as version_datefrom
from xmltable('/persons/person/version'
  passing xmltype('<persons>
  <person code="SNIPER">
    <type code="SINGLE" />
    <version code="1" dateFrom="2015-03-20T12:34:56+04:00" />
    <version code="2" dateFrom="2012-06-15T23:00:00+00:00" />
  </person>
</persons>')
  columns person_code varchar2(10) path './../@code',
    type_code varchar2(10) path './../type/@code',
    version_code number path '@code',
    version_datefrom timestamp with time zone path '@dateFrom'
);
```